# plotting difference intervals of two vectors

Tags: plotting

IF $a=\{2,6,8,18,20,24,26\}$ and $b=\{0,5,3,10,15,21,25\}$. I want the interval of the pairwise differences, that is, [0,2], [5,6], etc showing by lines in plots.
I don't know the command for it. I tried for the difference "a-b" and plot but it gives only the points on the graph. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Example

**Code**

```
NumberLinePlot[(Interval @ # & /@ Transpose[{b, a}]), PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

**Output**

[image: example output]

**Reference**

[Interval](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html)
[Transpose](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)
[NumberLinePlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberLinePlot.html)

Comment: very instructive answer +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `NumberLinePlot` -- which is a version 10 function -- one can customize a `Graphics` function.

```
plot[
   from_List,
   to_List, opts___] /; Length[b] == Length[a] :=
 Module[{z = 0, lines},
  lines = Apply[
    Module[{ends},
      ends = {{#1, z}, {#2, z}};
      z++;
      {Gray, Dashed, Thin, Line[{{#[[1]], 0}, #}] & /@ ends,
       ColorData[3][z], Dashing[{}], Thick, Point[ends], 
       Line[ends]}] &,
    Transpose[{from, to}], 1];
  Graphics[{Thick, PointSize[Medium], lines}, opts]
  ]
```

For example:

```
plot[b, a,
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: BoLe, could you point out more clearly what you perceive as different between your answer and that by @E.Doroskevic above? You both use `NumberLinePlot`, and frankly the other answer is rather more readable at first glance.

Comment: @MarcoB My answer actually utilizes `Graphics` directly.

Comment: Ah! I apologize, I misread your answer. Thank you for adding the clarification! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand what the aim. Here is one interpretation.

As Kuba points out in comment:

`ListPlot[{a,b},Filling -> {2 -> {1}}, PlotStyle -> Blue]`

suffices.

**Original answer**

```
a = {2, 6, 8, 18, 20, 24, 26} ;
b = {0, 5, 3, 10, 15, 21, 25};
int = Inner[Sort@List@## &, a, b, List];
ListPlot[Transpose@int, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Comment: `ListPlot[{a, b},...` works too, unless I missed something. I still don't know what is OP's goal though.

Comment: @Kuba D'Oh...I guess missing the obvious, Thanks!:)